# How to create javascript chat

Tags: javascript, html, chat

How to create js simple chat.
Only with js, html, css.
I don't want have a php, Ruby, C, C#, C++ or other server languages.
Please help.

Comment: So how do you expect to store the chat data? Also, this isn't a place to request free source code. I'm sure you can do some research or find some free source online?

Comment: Please read the site rules. SO is not made to provide complete solution. Its goal is to help people to improve and resolve problem. Try to do something then if you have problems come back to ask  here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered looking at Firebase? https://www.firebase.com/

Login and have a look at the 5 min tutorial and see how it works, its very easy to use, here is a chat I made with it already a while back - http://polydev.co.za/lab/experiments/chat/ - I obviously made it as generic as possible but the possibilities is endless and you can also have a look at polymer (What I used to make the components and the UI for the chat app)

Everything is done through JSON on firebase - Good Luck

Comment: Well played man! I use this for practically everything (Firebase) becuase I actually dont care for server side languages that much, now I can be awesome at front end and make awesome cloud based apps. have fun man!

Answer (score 0):

I think FireBase is exactly what you need.
You only need to have a bit of JS knowledge.

Check out this neat tutorial to get started:

https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted

Comment: Yes. But "Torean" send this

Comment: Correct, he was a tad faster than me.

Comment: Sorry for my Comment.